# Responsive sidenav in Angular Material, nothing appears

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

in order to try the following example aboout an angular material responsive sidenav

https://medium.com/@lopesgon/angular-material-a-responsive-sidenav-ef1d06b37986

I created a component with exactly the included code but nothing appears. How can I solve the problem?

I already searched for some solutions and fixed the version problem (in html file, not more "md" but "mat". Only error in browser console was solved, but nothing appeared.

View:

```html
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav [opened]="screenWidth > 840" [mode]="(screenWidth > 840) ? 'side' : 'over'">
    <div class="sidenav-header">
      <a routerLink="/"><h5>Hello world!</h5></a>
    </div>
  </md-sidenav>

  <div [ngStyle]="{'display' : (screenWidth > 840) ? 'none' : 'block'}">
    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Toggle sidenav when display is block
    </button>
  </div>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Component:

```html
screenWidth: number;

constructor() {
  // set screenWidth on page load
  this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  window.onresize = () => {
    // set screenWidth on screen size change
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you check the browser  console and tell us what is the error shown there ?

Comment: As told, no error appears in browser console. The once error I saw, it was before this post; and I have already solved. It was an error caused by Material version (I change md with mat). But this is not more related to the actual problem. At the moment, no browser error. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are ya applying any css to body or html?

Comment: No, no css to body or html